# Installing Yii 2 starter kit on Windows error: `'cp' is not recognized .. event returned with error code 1`

Tags: yii2

How to solve it when installing Yii 2 starter kit on Windows with the recommended command `composer run-script docker:build`, why this error happens?

````
'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Script cp .env.dist .env handling the build:env event returned with error code 1
Script @build:env was called via docker:build```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because normally the command cp is not available at the Ms Windows operating system
It must be currently edited in the composer.json file in the root directory, the `scripts->build.env` part must have changed `cp` command to `copy` as a temporal workaround

```
scripts": {
    "build:env": [
      "cp .env.dist .env"
    ],
```

to

```
scripts": {
    "build:env": [
      "copy .env.dist .env"
    ],
```